# How do I add a delay inbetween drawing an object?

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener

So i have a program that has a robot going through the maze. When it runs, it draws every position the robot has been in at the same time. I looked up Swing Timers, but I am confused about Action Listeners. Where would i create the ActionListener class? And what would I put inside it?

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;





public class RightRobotTest 
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{


    JFrame rightFrame = new JFrame();

    rightFrame.setSize(600, 400);
    rightFrame.setTitle("Right Robot");
    rightFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    RightMazeComponent Rcomponent = new RightMazeComponent();
    rightFrame.add(Rcomponent);

    rightFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

   rightFrame.setVisible(true);

/*   //Timer
     Timer timer = new Timer(5000, actionPerfromed());

     timer.start();
     try{
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
    }
    timer.stop();

*/



}
}

 class RightMazeComponent extends JComponent 
 {
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)

{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    int[][] outline ={       
                     {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                     {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
                     {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                     {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                     {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
                     {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                     {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                     {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}   };

    MazeBuilder original = new MazeBuilder(outline); 
    original.draw(g2);      

    Rectangle robot2 = new Rectangle (70, 20, 10, 10);
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.draw(robot2);


    int rPos = 1;
   int cPos = 0;
    int count2 = 0;

    //Right robot
    boolean rightFinish = true;


      int lastmove = 4;

     int Rchoice = original.MoveRightRobot(rPos, cPos);           


String move = "";
int value = 0;





while(rightFinish)
{
  move = Integer.toString(Rchoice) + Integer.toString(lastmove);
  value = Integer.parseInt(move);
  System.out.println(value);

switch (value)
{
 //down
  case 14:

   case 11:
  case 12:
 case 10:
                                      robot2.translate(0, 50);
                                      g2.draw(robot2);
                                      cPos++;
    Rchoice =    original.MoveRightRobot(rPos,cPos);
                                      lastmove = 0;
                                      count2++;
                                      break;
     //right
     case 24:               
     case 21:
    // case 23:
    case 20:
                                     robot2.translate(50,0);
                                     g2.draw(robot2);
                                     rPos++;
        Rchoice = original.MoveRightRobot(rPos,cPos);
                                     lastmove = 1;
                                     count2++;
                                     break;

   //left
   case 30:
   case 31:
   case 32:
   case 33:
   case 34:
                                     robot2.translate(-50, 0);
                                     g2.draw(robot2);
                                     rPos--;
              Rchoice = original.MoveRightRobot(rPos,cPos);
                                     lastmove = 2;
                                     count2++;
                                     break;

   //up
   case 40:
    case 41:
   case 42:
   case 43:
   case 44:
                                    robot2.translate(0, -50);
                                    g2.draw(robot2);
                                    cPos--;
           Rchoice = original.MoveRightRobot(rPos,cPos);
                                    lastmove = 3;
                                    count2++;
                                    break;

   //special cases

  case 23:                         
                                 if(original.MoveLeft(rPos,cPos) == true)
                                {
                                     robot2.translate(-50, 0);
                                     g2.draw(robot2);
                                     rPos--;
             Rchoice = original.MoveRightRobot(rPos,cPos);
                                     lastmove = 2;
                                     count2++;
                                     break;
                                }


                         else if(original.MoveRight(rPos, cPos) == true)
                                {
                                    robot2.translate(50,0);
                                     g2.draw(robot2);
                                     rPos++;
            Rchoice = original.MoveRightRobot(rPos,cPos);
                                     lastmove = 1;
                                     count2++;
                                     break;
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    robot2.translate(0, -50);
                                    g2.draw(robot2);
                                    cPos--;
             Rchoice = original.MoveRightRobot(rPos,cPos);
                                    lastmove = 3;
                                    count2++;
                                    break;
                                }


 case 22:                            
                                if(original.MoveDown(rPos, cPos) == true)
                                {
                                     robot2.translate(0, 50);
                                      g2.draw(robot2);
                                      cPos++;
        Rchoice = original.MoveRightRobot(rPos,cPos);
                                      lastmove = 0;
                                      count2++;
                                      break;
                                }

                             else if(original.MoveLeft(rPos, cPos) == true)
                                {
                                     robot2.translate(-50, 0);
                                     g2.draw(robot2);
                                     rPos--;
             Rchoice = original.MoveRightRobot(rPos,cPos);
                                     lastmove = 2;
                                     count2++;
                                     break;
                                 }

                                 else
                                 {
                                     robot2.translate(0, -50);
                                    g2.draw(robot2);
                                    cPos--;
            Rchoice = original.MoveRightRobot(rPos,cPos);
                                    lastmove = 3;
                                    count2++;
                                    break;
                                 }





}//Switch end
if(cPos == 6)
      {
        rightFinish = false;
        System.out.println("RIGHT ROBOT FINISH");
      }
      if(count2 == 25)
      {
            rightFinish = false;
            System.out.println("Right Robot Error.");
      }

    }


}



//BUILDS MAZE AND INCLUDES METHODS THAT CHECK WHAT MOVES ARE FREE
 class MazeBuilder
  {                 
    int[][] outline ={       
                     {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                     {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
                     {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                     {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                     {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
                     {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                     {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                     {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}   };

public  MazeBuilder(int[][] maze)
{
}
public void draw(Graphics2D g2)
{

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        /*if (outline[i][j] == 2)
        {
        Rectangle robot = new Rectangle( i, j*50, 50, 50);
            g2.draw(block);
        }*/

        if (outline[i][j] == 1)
        {
        Rectangle wall = new Rectangle( i*50, j*50, 50, 50);
            g2.draw(wall);
            g2.fill(wall);
        }
    }
}


 }

    int rowpos = 1;
    int colpos = 1;

    boolean down = true;
    boolean up = true;
    boolean left = true;
    boolean right = true;

  public boolean MoveDown(int rowpos, int colpos)
    {
        if(colpos != 6 && outline[rowpos][colpos+1] == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

public boolean MoveUp(int rowpos, int colpos)
{
    if (colpos != 0 && outline[rowpos][colpos - 1] == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {   
            return false;
        }
}

public boolean MoveLeft(int rowpos, int colpos)
{
    if (rowpos != 0 && outline[rowpos - 1][colpos] == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean MoveRight(int rowpos, int colpos)
{
    if( outline[rowpos + 1][colpos] == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}   

 //RETURNS VALUE AS TO WHICH DIRECTION ROBOT SHOULD MOVE

 public int MoveRightRobot(int rPos, int cPos)
 {
        boolean down = MoveDown(rPos,cPos);
        boolean up = MoveUp(rPos, cPos);
        boolean left = MoveLeft(rPos, cPos);
        boolean right = MoveRight(rPos, cPos);
        int RC = 7;

        if(right == true)
        {
            RC = 2;
        }

        else if (down == true)
        {
            RC = 1;
        }

        else if (left == true)
        {
            RC = 3;
        }

        else if (up == true)
        {
            RC = 4;
        }
        return RC;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to post all that code to illustrate your problem ? Can't you reduce your problem to a few lines of code ?

Comment: @EricLeibenguth i thought that was the way to do it based off of research

Answer (score 2):

There is way too much code posted in the question to study it and adjust it. Instead, here a high-level outline of what you will need if you want to let your robot move through a maze.

You want to have a sort of loop which:

- paint the maze with the robot at its current position
- calculate the next position of the robot
- move the robot to this new position, and paint the maze with the robot in this new position. Make sure that there is enough delay between this step and the first step so that a human can follow this

You were on the right track by wanting to use a Swing Timer. If you want for example to update the position of the robot every second, you would write a `Timer` which does:

```
Timer timer = new Timer( 1000, action -> {
  newPosition = calculateNewPosition();
  setNewPositionOfRobotInMaze( maze, newPosition);
  maze.repaint();
  if ( robotReachedEnd() ){
    ((Timer)action.getSource()).stop();
  }
});
timer.setRepeats( true );
timer.start();
```

Each time a second has passed, the timer will be triggered which in turn will trigger the action listener. The code in the action listener will update the robots position and ask the maze to do a repaint.

You might also want to read the [Swing concurrency guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) which clearly explains why you should not even bother with an attempt which uses `Thread.sleep` in combination with Swing code.

Answer (score -1):

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

//code here

}, 1000, 0);
```

Timer scheduleAtFixedRate method parameters:
TimerTask - contains code;
delay - between each run;
startDelay - if it should delay before starting the timer (runs once)

Comment: Using a `java.util.Timer` instance might work, but then you need to take special precautions to avoid Swing threading issues.

Comment: True, but i consider it worth the risk as I find threads with sleep() inefficient  and liable to thread exceptions

Comment: Then why not use a `javax.swing.Timer`, or use `SwingUtilities#invokexxx` and get rid of the potential threading issues ?

Comment: I did not know of `javax.swing.Timer`.

Answer (score -2):

You may use new Java 8 lambda expression for handle timer event

```
Timer timer = new Timer(5000, action -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: This will block the EDT for 5 seconds